# gdb attach permission question (ptrace_scope is read-only)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, docker, gdb

When using gdb to attach to the process. It shows

> Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
>   process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
>   again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
>   ptrace: Operation not permitted.

As root I use `echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`;
then it shows:

> bash: /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope: Read-only file system

How can I fix this problem? 
The content of `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` is `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0`

Comment: Can you try attaching that process with `sudo`?. And for the Read-only system you just remount your rootfs using `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` and then try.

Comment: What kind of installation are you working on? Is this some kind of virtualized environment?

Answer (score 7):

In docker you can now use the `--privileged` option, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

```
docker exec --privileged -ti <container> bash
```

In privileged mode, gdb just works without any modifications to ptrace_scope.

Answer (score 0):

To use a more granular approach, `cap_add` can also be used. The flag that works for me is `SYS_PTRACE`. This works in the CLI and in docker-compose files. For swarm you need to have at least Docker 20.10.0